# how can i get http://www value in php

Tags: php

i want to save the whole URL in my database 
i get the domain name using

```
=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
```

but how can i get it along with http://www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget running on possible non standard ports.  And always test to see if your request was done through https, don't test for port numbers to determine ssl.

```
$uri = "http".($_SERVER['HTTPS']?'s':'')."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].(($_SERVER['HTTPS']&&$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']!='443')||(!$_SERVER['HTTPS']&&$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']!='80')?":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']:"").$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 2):

you write it manually
"http://www.".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

Comment: thanks guy i also have to do it but search for a specific term but hope this will help for me

Answer (score 2):

What about this? :

$self = "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."";

You can even get the arguments after the page name

Comment: I wouldn’t use *PHP\_SELF* but *REQUEST\_URI*.

Comment: combining answers for a clean solution you can do: if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=="443" ){ $self = "https://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; }else{ $self = "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; }

Comment: or using HTTPS    "http".($_SERVER['HTTPS']?"s":"")."://", but the correct way, is to append the port, and check to see if ssl is turn on, on that port, technically, the standard http could have ssl turn on, in that case the url would be `https://www.myexample.com:80/`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` already contains the "www", if that was the requested host. All you need to append is the protocol (http:// or https://).

You can determine which the site was accessed through by looking at the port -- `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` will be 443 for https://